# Get the right relevance for multivalue field search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an entity that can have an arbitrary number of titles. In some cases there are dozens and even hundreds titles per entity.

These titles are stored in elasticsearch in a single field as an array.
The field has a complex analyzer with a complex tokenizer.

The problem is that elastic considers array field (field with a set of values) to тв a single "string", and the relevance of search results is calculated as a total relevance across the entire "string". But what I need is the relevance of one particular matched array element.

Below is a very simplified example.

Create index

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/tests'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/tests' -d'{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer",
          "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": "3",
          "max_gram": "12",
          "token_chars": ["letter", "digit"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Populate index

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/tests/test' -d'{ "id": 1, "name": ["text"] }'
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/tests/test' -d'{ "id": 2, "name": ["text", "text"] }'
```

Search

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/tests/test/_search' -d'{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "text"
    }
  }
}'
```

Results

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": { "total": 5, "successful": 5, "skipped": 0, "failed": 0 },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.7911257,
    "hits": [{
      "_index": "tests",
      "_type": "test",
      "_id": "AWOtIL2gdpqdbX7hdDXg",
      "_score": 0.7911257,
      "_source": { "id": 2, "name": [ "text", "text" ] }
    }, {
      "_index": "tests",
      "_type": "test",
      "_id": "AWOtIL0ldpqdbX7hdDXf",
      "_score": 0.51623213,
      "_source": { "id": 1, "name": [ "text" ] }
    }]
  }
}
```

As you can see **id:2** has relevance **0.7911257**, and **id:1** has relevance **0.51623213**.

I need both results to have the same relevance.

Is there any way to achieve it?

I know of two solutions to the problem, but both do not suit me. Perhaps there are some other options?

a) When number of titles is relatively small, titles can be stored each in separate field: name_0, name_1, name_2, etc.
These fields can be queries using **dis_max** request with **tie_breaker: 0** and relevance will be good.

```
"query": {
  "dis_max": {
    "queries": [
      { "match": { "name_0": "text" } },
      { "match": { "name_1": "text" } },
      { "match": { "name_2": "text" } }
    ],
    "tie_breaker": 0,
    "boost": 1
  }
}
```

b) Each title can be stored in elastic in a separate row

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/tests/test' -d'{ "product_id": 1, "name": "text" }'
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/tests/test' -d'{ "product_id": 2, "name": "text" }'
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/tests/test' -d'{ "product_id": 2, "name": "text" }'
```

In this case the results have to be further aggregated by product_id. So we get problems with results pagination and further aggregation of the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think  adding to your `name` field:

`"index_options": "docs"`

Will do the magic.

This setting will say to ES to don't care about TF of this field.

Check [Theory in relevance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html) if you want to know more.

Comment: This helps a lot. Thank you!